# Find all words from a list of letters, including duplicate letters?

Tags: python, string, permutation, repeat

I am trying to write a Python script that more or less mimics the New York Times game Spelling Bee (if you've played it). I have a code that prints out all the words from a list of letters, but I want to be able to repeat letters. For example, `fsde` produces nothing, but I want `feed` to be part of the results. Another example is the letters `etmxr` to produce `extreme` (Basically any letter can be repeated as many times as possible if the language has a word that allows it). Here is the code I have using `itertools` so far:

```
import itertools
import enchant

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
answer = []

user_input = input("Input letters here: ")
center = input("Input center letter here: ")

while len(center)>1 or center not in user_input:
    center = input("Either you entered a letter not in the first input, or you entered more than one letter. Try again: ")

letters = [x.lower() for x in user_input]

words = d
for t in range(4, len(user_input)):
    for m in itertools.permutations(user_input, t):
        a = "".join(m)
        if center in a:
            if d.check(a):
                answer.append(a)

print(answer)
```

Right now you just enter letters and get all the words from them, and that's all I want right now. If there's any way to get a double or triple letter I would really appreciate it.

I have scoured google and stackoverflow to no avail, I got the original code from a video but it doesn't have repeated letters and even though I now fully understand `permutations` I can't get multiple letters haha. I've tried `product` and `combination` with no luck, and a lot more but I think it's just a methodology thing I have wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't need any combinatorics for this, just a simple set comparison:

```
letters = 'etmxr'

with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as fp:
    for word in fp:
        if set(word.strip()).issubset(letters):
            print(word, end='')
```

result:

```
e
eer
em
eme
emeer
emmer
emmet
er
ere
err
ex
exert
exter
extreme
m
me
meet
meeter
...etc
```

Comment: This does work, however I needed to find a different list of english words (the enchant dictionary is not iterable) as well as add `if word in words: print(word)` as well as remove the `end=''` just in case anyone is trying to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the enchant module, but if you can iterate over all the words in the dictionary this should work:

```
user_letter_set = set(user_input)
valid_words = [word for word in d if user_letter_set >= set(word)]
```

The set comparison operator `>=` checks if `set(word)` is a subset of `user_letter_set`. Or in other words, if `user_letter_set` contains each type of letter found in `set(word)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with sets:

```
words={}
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as wf:
    for w in wf:
        w=w.lower().rstrip()
        key=frozenset(w)
        words.setdefault(key, set()).add(w)
    
tgt=frozenset('etmxr')
for fs in words:
    if fs<=tgt:
        k=''.join(sorted(fs))
        print(f"\"{k}\"=>{words[fs]}")
```

Prints:

```
"e"=>{'e'}
"er"=>{'eer', 'er', 're', 'reree', 'ree', 'ere', 'err'}
"em"=>{'emm', 'me', 'em', 'eme', 'mem'}
"emr"=>{'reem', 'mer', 'emmer', 'emeer', 'mere'}
"emt"=>{'emmet', 'emmett', 'teem', 'mete', 'met', 'meet'}
"ex"=>{'ex'}
"ertx"=>{'exert', 'exter'}
"emrtx"=>{'extreme'}
"m"=>{'m'}
"emrt"=>{'retem', 'meter', 'teemer', 'remeet', 'term', 'meeter', 'metrete', 'termer'}
"mr"=>{'mr'}
"r"=>{'r'}
"ert"=>{'teeterer', 'tree', 'retree', 'tret', 'teerer', 'teeter', 'ret', 'terret', 'reet', 'terete', 'tetter', 'retter', 'teer'}
"emrx"=>{'remex'}
"erx"=>{'rex'}
"t"=>{'t'}
"et"=>{'tete', 'teet', 'tee', 'te'}
"etx"=>{'text'}
"x"=>{'x'}
```